# What ways are there to attract more people to a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228483/will-the-zombie-siege-event-happen-on-a-mushroom-island), but it has low views (The last time I checked it had 31 views). It also has 3 votes and a "Favorite" star, so it's clearly a decent question, but it seems people do not look at it.

What ways (others than posting elsewhere and the starting a bounty) are there to attract more people?

Note: The numbers are given in the moment of writing.

Comment: Well, I guess this is a good way to make it seen.

Answer (score 6):

Post a bounty, link it on your favourite social media sites. Other than that, it's mostly just a waiting game. Sometimes things stay at low views/votes, there's even a related badge (Tumbleweed). Sometimes all of a sudden it gets a pile of views as people google for that issue. It's all dependent on things like how popular the game is, how popular that particular issue is, and so on. Unfortunately, someone favouriting the question doesn't guarantee that the Internet as a whole will come kicking down our door for that information, as nice as that would be. Like everything it's mostly up to chance, and the whims and needs of the internet as a whole, which can change at any moment.

Comment: There aren't really any other ways than that, though, so I would be surprised if you got an answer, as there isn't any real way to get attention for a question other than what I have described.

Comment: I put the first options as an exception. Anyway,the game is popular. It is Minecraft.

Comment: @john you might just have to wait and be patient. Just because a game is popular doesn't mean your question will be, necessarily. It's not something we can really predict or anything, beyond you doing as I described.